# Factoring an ideal in a number field into prime ideals

Tags: packages, number-theory

I'd like to factor an ideal in a number field into prime ideals, exactly as in this example from the [Sage documentation](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/number_fields/sage/rings/number_field/number_field_ideal.html):

```
sage: K.<a> = NumberField(x^4 + 23); K
Number Field in a with defining polynomial x^4 + 23
sage: I = K.ideal(19); I
Fractional ideal (19)
sage: F = I.factor(); F
(Fractional ideal (19, 1/2*a^2 + a - 17/2)) * (Fractional ideal (19, 1/2*a^2 - a - 17/2))
```

> What is the easiest way to achieve this in Mathematica?

It doesn't seem there is any built-in functionality for this. Is there are package available that I'm not seeing? Or should I just call PARI, via mathlink or a shell?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a general approach but in a world where 19 and x^4+23 define our number field, a decomposition can be found by factoring the polynomial.

```
InputForm[Factor[x^4+23,Modulus->19]]                                   

(* Out[3]//InputForm= (2 + 2*x + x^2)*(2 + 17*x + x^2) *)
```

The upshot is that the ideal `<19,x^4+23>` in `Z[x]` is the intersection of
`<19,2+2*x+x^2>` and `<19,2+17*x+x^2>`.

Comment: Thanks -- I guess I should have given a harder example. :-)